# Multiple logistic regression models into one forest plot using forest_model in R

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, r-forestplot

I want to plot multiple logistic regression models (ORs with 95%CIs of certain predictors) into one figure, using the `forestmodel` package in R.

Using this package I can produce individual forest plots, but I can't figure out how to merge them.

```
# Load packages and data
library(tidyverse)
library(forestmodel)

mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
str(mydata)

> 'data.frame': 400 obs. of  4 variables:
>  $ admit: int  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
>  $ gre  : int  380 660 800 640 520 760 560 400 540 700 ...
>  $ gpa  : num  3.61 3.67 4 3.19 2.93 3 2.98 3.08 3.39 3.92 ...
>  $ rank : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 1 4 4 2 1 2 3 2 ..

# Convert rank to factor. 
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)

# Fit two models predicting university admission based on rank of high school and gpa or gre.
mylogit1 <- glm(admit ~ gre + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
mylogit2 <- glm(admit ~ gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")

# Produce forest plots
plot1 <- forest_model(mylogit1)
plot1
plot2 <- forest_model(mylogit2)
plot2
```

I have tried several ways to plot both models into one figure:

```
# I tried several solutions:
forest_model(mylogit1, mylogit2) # after each other, or combined with c("mylogit1", "mylogit2")
forest_model(model_list = c(plot1, plot2)) #the same but with the model_list function

plotlist <- list(plot1, plot2) #making a list first and putting that in.
forest_model(model_list = c("plot1", "plot2"))
```

Regrettably, nothing worked. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is doable if you make seperate forest plots with the `forest_model` function in stead of `forest_models`, and arrange them with the `ggarrange` function from the `ggpubr` package as follows:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2, nrow=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this problem/question:

The solution is to add a list of models not forest_model outputs as an argument of model_list. OP created individual forest_model plots and then tried to use a list of those as an argument to model_list.

```
modelGlucose <- glm(EndPoint ~ Age + Sex + Glucose,data=data, family=binomial())
modelHbA1c <- glm(EndPoint ~ Age + Sex + HbA1c, data=data, family=binomial())

models <- list(Glucose=modelGlucose,HbA1c=modelHbA1c)

forest_model(model_list=models,covariates=c("Glucose","HbA1c"), merge_models=T)
```